# how to fill N/A values with scaling in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame by pandas, and it contains a lots of NaN values.

the following figure is about data what I have,

|  | 2ndFlrSF | SalePrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 854 | 208500 |
| 1 | 0 | 181500 |
| 2 | 866 | 223500 |
| 3 | 756 | 140000 |
| 4 | 1053 | 250000 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1455 | 694 | 175000 |
| 1456 | 0 | 210000 |
| 1457 | 1152 | 266500 |
| 1458 | 0 | 142125 |
| 1459 | 0 | 147500 |

[image]

and next one is **what I expected.**

[image]

I have tried to fill NaN values with average(mean) and most frequents, but it is not what i want to.

[image]
[image]

Is there any package or method to fill the values with scaled for this?

one thing I would like to comment is, I do NOT want to drop this values.

if any solution, please let me know. thanks.

EDITED:

I found [this question (dataframe-column-interpolation-weigthed-by-values-of-another-column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66353252/dataframe-column-interpolation-weigthed-by-values-of-another-column), but it doesn't work.

I did:

```
df[['2ndFlrSF', 'SalePrice']].sort_values('SalePrice').set_index('SalePrice')['2ndFlrSF'].interpolate(method='index')

# doesn't work neither
# df2 = df[['2ndFlrSF', 'SalePrice']].sort_values('SalePrice')
# df2.interpolate(method='linear')
```

but got result:

```
34900        0
35311        0
37900      368
39300        0
40000      668
          ... 
582933    1088
611657       0
625000    1796
745000    2065
755000    1872
Name: 2ndFlrSF, Length: 1460, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you add few rows from the dataframe and maybe a concise description of the fields? Also, please elaborate a bit about your expectation in filling these nan values. E.g. in case of time series data, it might make sense to forward or backward fill missing values, but it might not be applicable in other scenarios.

Comment: Could you explain in English or better in mathematics how you think variables are linked together. Additionally could you post a representative sample of the data?

Comment: @Bitswazsky adding rows is ok, but I prefer to update rows. and it is not time-series data, just amounts of something.

Comment: @jlandercy I updated the post to add sample data. I think there is a trend line. so I am wondering there is generic method to fill with estimation values by trend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use interpolation to estimate your missing data with help of its neighbors.
there are different Interpolation methods like:

linear: simply means to estimate a missing value by connecting dots in a straight line in increasing order

```
a.interpolate()
```

polynomial interpolation: is filling missing values with the lowest possible degree that passes through available data points

```
a.interpolate(method="polynomial", order=2)
```

padding: this means filling missing values with the same value present above them in the dataset.

```
a.interpolate(method="pad", limit=2)
```

so you can simply replace nan values as follow (let's suppose a is your data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.Series([0, 1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, 7])
a.interpolate(method="pad", limit=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. but what I want is, can value interpolate by another value? as passed by pair or something..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, please be more specific

Comment: sorry for my english. well.. I mean, when fill values in series A, using interpolate with weight from B. e.g. A[i] = B[i] * (A[k] / B[k]). (index `i` is for NaN, and `k` not for NaN)

Comment: I can't see why you need to do this and also in your data there is no B, unless you, manually, create a series as your weight vector. but it doesn't sound like a good idea because if you use the polynomial or linear method a weight vector will be generated automatically and fill the missing value with the best interpolation definitely better than a handmade weight vector.

Comment: I understood and agree with you. When I tried and posted this question, I didn't think about polynomial and linear method. but now, i know it is wrong way to fill blanks. what I tried is just mocking data. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

I still doesn't know the method in Pandas. but I know using this approach is
unnormal.

BTW, for answer, resolve with implementation by myself.

```py
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

# fill src[] by weight from dst[]
def interpolate(dst: list, src: list):
    n = len(src)
    a = [[dst[i], src[i], i, src[i] / dst[i]] for i in range(n)]
    a.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
    res = deepcopy(a)
    for i in range(n):
        if res[i][1] != 0: continue
        l = i
        while l >= 0 and res[l][1] == 0: l -= 1
        r = i
        while r < n and res[r][1] == 0: r += 1

        if l != -1 and r != n:
            step = (a[r][3]-a[l][3]) / (r-l+1)
            if step != 0:
                c = np.arange(a[l][3], a[r][3], step)
                for j in range(len(c)-2):
                    res[l+j+1][1] = a[l+j+1][0] * c[j]
        elif l == -1:
            for j in range(r+1):
                res[j][1] = a[j][0] * a[r][3]
        else:
            for j in range(n-l):
                res[l+j][1] = a[l+j][0] * a[l][3]
    return list(map(lambda p: p[1], sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[2])))
```

**Before interplote**

[image: Before]

**After interpolate values with SalePrice**

[image: After]

I uploaded code and sample data.

you can see sample data and its result from: https://gist.github.com/joonas-yoon/f5d01db4470ff87e442dc01c99f04c47#file-sample-txt

Thanks for all of comments and replies.

Comment: one option is to build a linear regression model and impute the missing values using the regression coefficients.